# 64 bit features in a 32 bit application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, x86-64, sse

I have a 32 bit application which I plan to run on 64bit Windows 7.

At this stage I cannot convert the entire application to 64 bit due to dependencies to thirdparty functionality.

However, I would like to have access to the xmm9-xmm15 registers in my SSE optimizations and also use the additional registers which 64 bit cpus provides in general while executing my application.

Is this possible to achieve with some compiler flag?

Comment: Pester said third party for 64-bit components.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me that the best way would be to divide your program in **more than one executable**. The EXE compiled as 64bit can communicate with another 32-bit EXE used the 32-bit thirdparty DLL which you need. You will have some overhead in the communication and will have to implement Starting/Stopping of depended process, but you will have clear program architecture.

If you develop native C++ application you can implement the second EXE for example as the COM++ out-of-process object (LocalServer or even LocalService). You can consider the way to implement the COM server in C# (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/BuildCOMServersInDotNet.aspx)). Sometimes that way could simplify the implementation and you can use the advantages of both .NET and native programming.

Comment: So you are basically saying, "don't" :-)

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: What do you mean with "don't"? There are not only black and white in the real live. Ronag has the problem and he asked for an advice on the question "what should he do in the situation?" I answered which way I prefer.

Comment: Sure, I am just kidding with you.  And your solution is in most situations the best, I would assume. Why do something odd when you can something normal to solve a problem. (But I kind of like the odd solutions sometimes, just because they are different.)

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: OK! I understand you absolute.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. See [this example](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2004-August/005020.html) for how.

As Christopher pointed out, this technique will not always work, but for this express purpose, to jump into a few lines of handcrafted assembly and make use of more registers, then put the result somewhere and then jump back to 32 bit mode, it should work out just fine.

Comment: Thanks. That example seems to be for linux though? And I don't quite understand that inline assembly syntax. Would you mind to clearify?

Comment: Introduction to AT/T syntax:  http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax   Also, I assumed that the same technique would work on Windows too, but I could be wrong of course. @ronag

Comment: This could work partially on windows. But you cannot execute arbitrary code which does not know the limitations. You will have problems with exception handling, SEH and C++. You will have problems calling kernel mode code, because kernel mode code will look at the process to figure out how to use the passed data.

Comment: As far as I know, WOW64 zeroes out some SSE registers on syscalls (while Win32 ignores them). Also, Win32 surely does not preserve their contents during a task switch (simply because there is no such thing officially on a 32 bit CPU). Are you sure this can work at all?

Comment: @Damon, I guess if the registers were stored manually between syscalls.